# Buy 2 for £10 - Price Rule

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules

Im after a solution where by the following would apply:

`Buy any 2 maps (from CATEGORY A or CATEGORY B) for £10`

Is there a simple way to achieve this in Magento or is it looking like an Extension solution?

I have tried setting up a Precent of product price discount rule but this only applies when theres 2 of the same SKU

TIA

Answer (score 0):

A fixed price is not possible unfortunately, you could only do percentage or buy x get y free.

You would need to use an extension now to make this work.

In case you would like to do % then you would need to go on like this

Conditions:

> If ALL of these conditions are TRUE: If total quantity is 2 for a
>   sub-selection of the items in cart matching ALL of these conditions
>
> Category is one of [SELECT CATEGORY FROM LIST]